# Добавить поле в почтовый шаблон Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Ломаю голову второй день, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу изменить почтовый шаблон, чтобы когда клиент, делающий заказ на сайте, информационное письмо о том, что он сделал заказ содержало не просто название товара, но и также раздел и подраздел этого товара???? Если это имеет вес, то пользуюсь решением от аспро...

Вот как сейчас это выглядит - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть какой-нибудь PARRENTNAME или что-то подобное... Уверен, что ответ и решение простое, но сижу над этим вопросом уже очень длительное время и всё никак... Разные варианты пробовал...

Comment: Люди добрые хэлп) любой совет будет полезен... спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Решилось тем, что перезалил товары.